# Build Bamboo from Bitbucket, Deploy to Azure Cloud

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo

I'm looking for a solution using all Atlassian products similar to Visual Studio Online to build and deploy a .NET web application. Basic workflow would be:

1. Merge to Master (Git on Bitbucket)
2. Test/Build using Bamboo
3. Deploy to Azure Cloud (not Web Sites, not Virtual Machines)

Visual Studio Online does this quite easily ([hosted build controller](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/hosted-build-controller-vs), [deploy](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/deploy-to-azure-vs)), its all Microsoft so it works together nicely. I know Azure works with any Git repo directly, but I'm unsure how to bring the build and deploy steps into play together using Atlassian services.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Azure Command Line interfaces available on this page:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

I don't know Bamboo, but presumably there's a post-build step.  Embed the relevant commands to do the deployment.  Ask here for details as you get deeper.

Another option is the PowerShell cmdlets, though those would be harder to embed in your tools (I think). Same download page.

Comment: Basically Bamboo natively support MSBuild, batch script and can virtually execute any other application (python, Nunit test runner, etc...)

Comment: Specifically I am looking for a solution that has already been implemented, tested, documented. I know there is likely an extensive custom development series of scripts, but the time to create all this from scratch is too great.